# Cocoapods is not respecting the specification of a dependency from a podfile, when listed in a podspec

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

There's an issue with CocoaLumberjack when running with Xcode 9 and Swift 4, so I'm using the latest code from the master branch to resolve that issue. My podfile looks like so:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '11.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'MyProject' do
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack', :branch => 'master'
end
```

I've also made a podspec as I plan to use this project's work in other libraries:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  ...

  s.frameworks   = 'Foundation', 'UIKit', 'ARKit', 'CoreLocation', 'MapKit', 'SceneKit'
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'

  s.dependency 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
end
```

Now when I do `pod install` from another project, it installs both the CocoaLumberjack pod and my own project's pod, but then when I build, it gives the same CocoaLumberjack error. The version of CocoaLumberjack it's using is the one you'd get without specifying a particular branch, commit or version.

I can add the additional `:git` and `:branch` arguments to the dependency declaration in the podspec, but they are invalid when stated there. As far as I understand it, so long as you state the name of the dependency, it should take the rest of the specification about it from the project's podfile. But what I'm seeing here is that it's just treating it as though there is no further specification, and downloading the pod as named.

Comment: try removing the pod in your myProject podfile and add it in the podspec only

Comment: @ReinierMelian That wouldn't work, as its demo project wouldn't build, and the podspec still doesn't get to dictate which branch should be used.